# Bundling React-native code with a different configuration than Release

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to bundle my app that has a react native portion in it.

The `react-native` documentation says that I must use the `release` configuration to be able to bundle the application. However, in my project, the `release` build configuration is replicated by another configuration named `appstore`, and changing this is a big undertaking since a lot will have to change including the CI.

How can I tell `React Native` to basically look for the `appstore` configuration and not `release` configuration where it decides if it should bundle the `React Native` components or not?

tl;dr: Need to ship my native ios app to production that has RN parts in it, but RN documentation says that I need to have the build configuration set to `release` but my project has `appstore` as the release build configuration.

I get this error: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is here. From what I know once you execute `react-native run-ios`, it generates a Xcode project. to which you can bundle(adhoc, appstore) or debug in what ever way you want for iOS. Can you add some more detail about  what you are doing? In form of code, command and all.

Comment: I already have a native codebase to which I'm adding this react native component. I now want to bundle the app with the RN code and not run development server. I don't have a release configuration in my app by design but it seems like RN only bundles your React code if you're building in release mode. How can I get RN to bundle my code for production without using Release build configuration?

Comment: I think we'll need to check what error it produce in order to get more clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [react-native-schemes-manager](https://github.com/blargity/react-native-schemes-manager), you can use Xcode build configurations / schemes with React Native, it says:

> Once the package is installed in your project, you just need to
>   configure it by adding an xcodeSchemes section to your package.json
>   and adding a postinstall script which will re-run the script whenever
>   you add or remove packages to/from your project:

```
{
    "xcodeSchemes": {
        "Debug": ["Staging", "Preflight"],
        "appstore": ["Beta"],
        "projectDirectory": "iOS"
    },
}
```

Note: I haven't used it personally, just thought it might be helpful to you.